# Upload more than 500MB video file at amazon s3 bucket and show error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Please any one tell me how to upload file more than 500mb at amazon s3 bucket ,because i am uploading file less than 500mb (like 470mb or 430mb) it's working fine but when upload 600mb 700mb file then  show error .and the error is

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: User Warning
Message:  S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file:
Filename: libraries/S3.php
Line Number: 224
```

when i run the phpinfo() function then show the same settings at these below.
My php.ini settings are

```
1. upload_max_filesize=2048M 
2. post_max_size=2048M
3. max_execution_time=3000 (50 minutes)
4. memory_limit=1024M
```

file read is 100% but when goes to write then shows error.I don't know where is the problem.

Thank's

Comment: Are you using multipart uploads for your large files? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#uploading-large-files-using-multipart-uploads

Comment: In Amazon documentation they said , upload upto 5gb file with single putobject.ANd if user want more than 5gb then use multipart uploading function.

Comment: The documentation also says "We encourage Amazon S3 customers to use Multipart Upload for objects greater than 100 MB." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html

Comment: But i check this function inputFile() and i see in which three conditions and if any condition is true then show error.and i also debug and i find !file_exists($file) condition is true and other condition are based on first condition and these are also true when first condition is true.so basically problem occur in !file_exists($file) , condition is below, "                                                                                                 if (!file_exists($file) || !is_file($file) || !is_readable($file)) {
 //show error
  } "

Comment: @HammayunRaza did you get solution, I am facing same.